# Front end of application is built in Laravel livewire and want to consume API's built in Lumen

Tags: laravel, jwt, lumen, laravel-livewire

I was handed over a project by my company, it was made in Laravel with livewire and Nova.The company wants me to redo the app by consuming API's written in Lumen.

The first thing that I want to ask is whether its a good idea and secondly how to go about storing jwt token in Laravel provided by the Lumen login API and use it in subsequent requests?

Answer (score 0):

First question you need to ask is why do they want to rebuild something existing under Laravel to Lumen. Lumen is basically a lightweight version of Laravel. If the idea is to seperate the frontends from the backend you could keep using Laravel, it can definitely be used to define APIs.

Regarding your second question, there are already some existing libraries (https://github.com/dusterio/lumen-passport ) which can help you use Laravel Passport in Lumen, so you shouldn't have any issue and you should be able to use your token everywhere.

Comment: Basically they want to make API's for the future in case there is a need for mobile app and secondly they are making all there current and existing projects to be API based.

Comment: OK, I get it, but you can definitely keep Laravel to transform the existing into an API. You don't need to use Lumen for this. If your application is already build with Laravel you can just refactor your code to return API responses instead of publishing blade views but you don't need to convert everything to Lumen to achieve that.

Comment: But what do will I need to do the with Front end that is built on live wire already, they want it to be powered by API's as well.

Comment: I am not familiar with Livewire but I think you can keep it to consume the API. You'll just have to change the way your app gets the data (from the API instead of what you're doing actually). But this would have been the same if you move to Lumen, you'll also have to change the way your frontend receives data. I feel you need to look a bit at the documentation and just define exactly what you want to achieve before starting coding anything.